# nlme estimates near zero variance for the random effects

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I am doing various analysis on a small sample. Basically, we have an experiment where 14 subjects (UID 1 ~ 14) used one of the 6 machines (MID 1 ~ 6) on 3 occasions (Sequence 1 ~ 3). Each time an outcome score was registered (between 1 ~ 100).

The test was double blind. The subjects were told they are measuring 3 different conditions while in reality they were either measuring conditions in sequence (A, B, A) or (B, A, B) randomly assigned to the machines and users). The objective was to see if `A` and `B` are different or not.

To see if there is any significant difference between the ratings for the conditions A and B, I tried to fit a simple, random intercept model using the `nlme` package in R. I tried:

```
f.1 <- lme(Score ~ Condition, random = ~1|UID, data)
```

However, for some reason `lme` fails to fit the model: it gives no error or warning but the variance of the fitted random effect is essentially zero:

```r
    > summary(f.1)
    Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
     Data: data 
           AIC      BIC   logLik
      349.3259 356.0815 -170.663
    
    Random effects:
     Formula: ~1 | UID
             (Intercept) Residual
    StdDev: 0.0009303203 15.98295
    
    Fixed effects: Score ~ Condition 
                   Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
    (Intercept) 77.47619  3.487766 27 22.213700  0.0000
    ConditionA  -0.85714  4.932446 27 -0.173776  0.8633
     Correlation: 
               (Intr)
    ConditionA -0.707
    
    Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
           Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
    -2.9704269 -0.4677603  0.2472873  0.7835730  1.4628682 
    
    Number of Observations: 42
    Number of Groups: 14
```

I tried doing the same thing using `lme4` and got the same results. The estimates for the intercept and the `Condition` factor is almost identical to a linear model if I use `lm`.

I am trying hard to understand what `lme` or `lmer` fail to estimate the random effect. I generated some data by simulation and both routines had no problem fitting the model so I doubt there is something wrong with the syntax of what I have used.

The data is here:

```
   UID MID Seq Score Condition
1    1   1   1    90  B
2    1   1   2    85  A
3    1   1   3    75  B
4    2   4   1    75  A
5    2   4   2    95  B
6    2   4   3    85  A
7    3   6   1    60  A
8    3   6   2    82  B
9    3   6   3    85  A
10   4   3   1    60  A
11   4   3   2    70  B
12   4   3   3    75  A
13   5   2   1    85  B
14   5   2   2    85  A
15   5   2   3    85  B
16   6   5   1    90  B
17   6   5   2    95  A
18   6   5   3   100  B
19   7   2   1    90  B
20   7   2   2    70  A
21   7   2   3    50  B
22   8   1   1    70  B
23   8   1   2    75  A
24   8   1   3    80  B
25   9   3   1    90  A
26   9   3   2    30  B
27   9   3   3    90  A
28  10   6   1    50  A
29  10   6   2    85  B
30  10   6   3    92  A
31  11   4   1    50  A
32  11   4   2    85  B
33  11   4   3    92  A
34  12   5   1    65  B
35  12   5   2    50  A
36  12   5   3    90  B
37  13   4   1    65  A
38  13   4   2    70  B
39  13   4   3    80  A
40  14   2   1    60  B
41  14   2   2   100  A
42  14   2   3    80  B
```

Comment: Not an answer, but some comments on your data. First off I am not sure whether fitting a linear model to the scores is appropiate here. The mean in group A is already 77.5 with a stdev of 16. That means the possible max value is just 1.4 standard deviations from the mean. This means your distribution will be skewed. Also you seem to assume that the score does not depend on where the subject is in his sequence (1,2,3) or if he is in sequence ABA or BAB.

Comment: You might be right. However, as a first step I like to fit a linear model and then take additional steps to make a better/more complex models. The problem is that the fitting procedure fails without warning.

Comment: Also, there might be a learning effect, true. If I add `Seq` as a covariate I can have an idea about it. However, with or without that, the procedure fails to fit the random effects.

Comment: The estimate is just very small. You just get a meaningful random effect if the variation between the individuals is larger than the error that would be expected when considering just inter-intravidual variance. Your stdev is 16, given 3 samples per subject you can estimate the individual means with an error of about 16/sqrt(3).  If the standard deviation of the individual means is of a magnitude consistent with that you won't get a meaningful random effect. 
That's why my comments matter, since if your model does not fit the data well your residual standard deviation might be too high.

Comment: I see. I like to expand the study to measure more subjects. But I don't think that the within subject variance would reduce a lot: the score is about their perception of delay, which is rather hard for individuals to assess. Based on what you said, it seems that increasing the sample size would not help much and we should focus more on possibly increasing the repetitions.

Comment: see http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#singular_fits for some more information ...

Comment: Thanks a lot @BenBolker. The approach based on the blme package seems interesting.

Comment: @BenBolker wow! I tried `blmer` in the simplest form and it converged with no problem `blmer(Score ~ Condition + (1 | UID), data)`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the question comments, the problem is a singuar fit. One solution to this, is to adopt a Bayesian approach which has apparently been a good solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the problem is singularity that the estimated variance of random intercepts is at its boundary zero. In such cases, `lme4` prints messages but `nlme` does not. However, you can use `nlme::interval()` to assess boundary issues. In fact, your model will produce the following error when finding confidence intervals.

```r
library(nlme)
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
Data <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE, text = "
    UID MID Seq Score Condition
1    1   1   1    90  B
2    1   1   2    85  A
3    1   1   3    75  B
4    2   4   1    75  A
5    2   4   2    95  B
6    2   4   3    85  A
7    3   6   1    60  A
8    3   6   2    82  B
9    3   6   3    85  A
10   4   3   1    60  A
11   4   3   2    70  B
12   4   3   3    75  A
13   5   2   1    85  B
14   5   2   2    85  A
15   5   2   3    85  B
16   6   5   1    90  B
17   6   5   2    95  A
18   6   5   3   100  B
19   7   2   1    90  B
20   7   2   2    70  A
21   7   2   3    50  B
22   8   1   1    70  B
23   8   1   2    75  A
24   8   1   3    80  B
25   9   3   1    90  A
26   9   3   2    30  B
27   9   3   3    90  A
28  10   6   1    50  A
29  10   6   2    85  B
30  10   6   3    92  A
31  11   4   1    50  A
32  11   4   2    85  B
33  11   4   3    92  A
34  12   5   1    65  B
35  12   5   2    50  A
36  12   5   3    90  B
37  13   4   1    65  A
38  13   4   2    70  B
39  13   4   3    80  A
40  14   2   1    60  B
41  14   2   2   100  A
42  14   2   3    80  B
")
summary(Model <- lme(Score ~ Condition, random = ~ 1 | UID, data = Data))
intervals(Model)
"Error in intervals.lme(Model) : 
  cannot get confidence intervals on var-cov components: Non-positive definite approximate variance-covariance
 Consider which = 'fixed'"
```

It means that the estimated variance is not positive, which is in line with a zero-variance case. The reason for singularity in this case is not incorrect syntax but the data characteristics. Before modeling, we need to explore the data in tables and plots.

```r
sd(Data$Score)
"15.79279"
Data %>%
  group_by(UID) %>% 
  summarize(Umean = mean(Score), Usd = sd(Score)) %>%
  summarize(REsd = sd(Umean), Usdm = mean(Usd))
"     UID Umean   Usd
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  83.3  7.64
 2     2  85   10   
 3     3  75.7 13.7 
 4     4  68.3  7.64
 5     5  85    0   
 6     6  95    5   
 7     7  70   20   
 8     8  75    5   
 9     9  70   34.6 
10    10  75.7 22.5 
11    11  75.7 22.5 
12    12  68.3 20.2 
13    13  71.7  7.64
14    14  80   20   
REsd 7.78
Usdm 14.0"
Data %>%
  group_by(UID) %>% 
  mutate(DM = Score - mean(Score)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  summarize(DMsd = sd(DM))
"13.8"
```

The standard deviation of `Score` is 15.8. After removing means by user, the standard deviation is on average 14.0, or more accurately 13.8, which does not reduce much. The standard deviation of user-specific means is 7.78, much smaller than the standard deviation of demeaned scores and will shrink further in random-effects estimators. Recall that random effects are user-specific sequence-average deviation from the ground mean that should make the within-subject variation smaller than the total variation. If within-subject variation equals the total variation, there are no random effects.

```r
Data <- Data %>% 
  group_by(UID) %>% 
  mutate(Group = if_else(
    Condition[1] == "B", "BAB", "ABA") %>% 
      factor(levels = c("ABA", "BAB"))) %>%
  ungroup()
ggplot(
  data = Data, 
  aes(x = factor(Seq), y = Score, group = UID, color = Group) ) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(
    ymin = ifelse(after_stat(ymin) < 0, 0, after_stat(ymin)), 
    ymax = ifelse(after_stat(ymax) > 100, 100, after_stat(ymax)), 
    group = Group, fill = Group), 
    method = "loess", span = 1, linetype = 0, show.legend = F) + 
  stat_smooth(
    geom = "line", aes(group = Group),
    method = "loess", span = 1, linewidth = 1, alpha = 0.7) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 0.2, alpha = 0.4, show.legend = F) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#2197DF", "#D14343")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#2197DF", "#D14343")) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0.1, 0, 0.1)) + 
  labs(x = "Sequence") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(
    legend.title = element_blank(), 
    legend.position = c(0.6, 0.2), 
    panel.grid = element_line(colour = "grey90", linewidth = 0.2)
  )
```

[image]

We can also view such data characteristics from a spaghetti plot. It shows no patterns that user-specific mean values deviate from the ground mean. In contrast, the variation within each user is so great that it is comparable with total variation. However, the comparison should not be made based on `Condition` but the first `Condition` each user experienced that sufficiently defines the two distinct experimental sequences, which is coded into `Group`. Groups ABA and BAB appear to have different means at three sequential stages that show linear effects on `Score`. Starting with B, the delay is longer than that starting with A but remains constant in additional stages, unlike those starting with A whose delay increases in the second and third stages. So we can use `Seq` as numeric instead of a factor and should have interaction between `Seq` and `Group` to allow different intercepts and slopes of `Seq` by `Group`.

```r
summary(Model <- lmer(Score ~ 1 + (1 | UID), data = Data))
summary(Model <- lmer(Score ~ Condition + (1 | UID), data = Data))
summary(Model <- lmer(Score ~ factor(Seq) + (1 | UID), data = Data))
summary(Model <- lmer(Score ~ Group + (1 | UID), data = Data))
summary(Model <- lmer(Score ~ Group * Seq + (1 | UID), data = Data))
"boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
REML criterion at convergence: 324.2
  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 UID      (Intercept)   0.0     0.00   
 Residual             220.4    14.85   
Number of obs: 42, groups:  UID, 14
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)    53.286      8.571   6.217
GroupBAB       24.810     12.122   2.047
Seq            10.643      3.968   2.682
GroupBAB:Seq   -9.929      5.611  -1.769"
```

Because the within-subject variation is as large as the total variation, any attempt to estimate random intercepts is challenging. `lme4::lmer()` shows boundary issues and zero variance in all specifications with random intercepts by `UID`.

```r
summary(Model <- gls(
  Score ~ Group * Seq, correlation = corCompSymm(form = ~ 1 | UID), data = Data))
intervals(Model, which = "var-cov")
" Correlation structure:
          lower       est.     upper
Rho -0.3180153 -0.1002069 0.2332579"
summary(Model <- gls(
  Score ~ Group * Seq, correlation = corAR1(form = ~ Seq | UID), data = Data))
intervals(Model, which = "var-cov")
" Correlation structure:
         lower        est.     upper
Phi -0.3811611 -0.05991643 0.2742381"
```

Without using random effects, we can still incorporate clustered errors by specifying error correlation patterns in generalized least squares. The above summary shows that the correlation is no different from zero in either a compound symmetry structure or an autoregressive process. Note that neither estimates nor confidence intervals of correlation coefficients are at boundary -1 or 1, which implies stable results.

```r
summary(Model <- gls(
  Score ~ Group * Seq, data = Data))
"       AIC      BIC    logLik
  334.2345 342.4224 -162.1173
                Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  53.28571  8.571399  6.216688  0.0000
GroupBAB     24.80952 12.121789  2.046688  0.0477
Seq          10.64286  3.967787  2.682316  0.0108
GroupBAB:Seq -9.92857  5.611298 -1.769390  0.0849"
summary(Model <- gls(
  Score ~ Group * Seq, weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | Seq), data = Data))
"Generalized least squares fit by REML
      AIC      BIC    logLik
  335.685 347.1481 -160.8425
Variance function:
 Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
 Formula: ~1 | Seq 
 Parameter estimates:
        1         2         3 
1.0000000 1.3269816 0.8687116 
                Value Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  53.36942  7.781308  6.858670  0.0000
GroupBAB     24.67001 11.004431  2.241825  0.0309
Seq          10.67273  3.395007  3.143656  0.0032
GroupBAB:Seq -9.97837  4.801265 -2.078279  0.0445
Residual standard error: 13.5885 
Degrees of freedom: 42 total; 38 residual"
```

The spaghetti plot shows that both ABA and BAB groups have similar spread in each stage, and both groups have slightly larger spread in the second stage. Therefore, we can use weighted least squares to allow error variance to vary by stage. As shown above, compared to OLS and random effects, WLS results in smaller standard errors and *p* values. However, both AIC and BIC prefer OLS.

In summary, not all longitudinal data require random-effects or fixed-effect estimators. When the between-subject deviation is small, within-subject variation is comparable with total variation, random effects approach zero variance, and simpler models may give better results.